# edit bibitem to specific reference journal

Tags: bibliographies

My journal required `\bibitem` reference style, after I  read many comments I succeed to convert my reference list `.bib` to `\bibitem` and get my `.bbl` file, I open it and copy past the references in the place of bibliography. The problem is that the reference does not appear like required from the journal.
My journal required this style.

> [7]  Li RTH, Chung SH. Digital boundary controller for single-phase grid-connected CSI. In:  IEEE 2008 Power Electronics Specialists Conference; 15–19 June 2008; Rhodes, Greece. New York, NY, USA: IEEE. pp. 4562-4568

But my reference appears like this:

> [7]  River T.H. Li, Henry S.H. Chung, and W. H. Lau. Digital boundary controller for single-phase grid-connected CSI.PESC Record - IEEE Annual Power Electronics Specialists Conference, pages 4562–4568, 2008

What I should do?

Comment: Please tell us what you're actually doing. E.g., are you building the bibliography entirely by hand, or do you use a tool such as BibTeX? If you use BibTeX, which bibliography style do you employ? Please be specific.

Comment: Your question suggests that you have switched from `.bib` to using a list of `\bibitem` entries. In that case,  you can simply type the entries using the desired final format.  You can find a guide in [this wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Manually_Managing_References). In your specific instance, something like `\bibitem{Li2008} Li RTH, Chung SH. Digital boundary controller for single-phase grid-connected CSI. In: IEEE 2008 Power Electronics Specialists Conference; 15–19 June 2008; Rhodes, Greece. New York, NY, USA: IEEE. pp. 4562-4568` will produce the output you are seeking.